# Which database in Java Android?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app in Android. I would like to attach a database (created in C++) to my app Android that my Android app could read. In which format should I create this database with my C++ program?

Answer (score 6):

Android provides a built in [**SQLite database**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db), which is used by the applications developed for it. The Android SDK provides a well-defined, easy-to-use API to this database, and as long as you don't have a real special need for your own database, I would suggest using it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at sqlite (www.sqlite.org/).

Answer (score 1):

sqlite - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

SqlLite is the built-in database. Portable across Android, iPhone, HTML5 and just about every embedded system.

I take it that your question is how to create a database on a host computer (using C++) and transfer it to the Android App. If so, then have your C++ program create a SqlLite database on your host computer and then either package the database with the app, or download it into the App's data folder from a server.

Answer (score 0):

For C++ program you can use [C/C++ Interface For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html). Check out the tutorial [An Introduction To The SQLite C/C++ Interface](http://www.sqlite.org/cintro.html).

Answer (score 0):

http://realm.io "Realm is a mobile database: a replacement for SQLite & Core Data 
Realm can save you thousands of lines of code & weeks of work, 
and lets you craft amazing new user experiences."